# Print file_get_contents into a div

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I have a few URLS that i am looping through and using `file_get_contents` to pull the html page, what i am trying to do is create a table on my website and have each row show the returned `HTML` for each page. The problem i am having is when printing out the html it covers up my full page rather that only inside my table cell.

I have tried using an `iframe` and setting the SRC to the URL instead but the website has this blocked.

Is there a way to stop the html from taking over the full page and contain it into a cell?

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags(file_get_contents(URL_OF_FILE))`. Raw HTML from those third party sites are messing with HTML structure of your page and broke the table layout.

Ex :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo file_get_contents('demofileurl');?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Suppose, demofileurl produces below output :

```
<div style="height:5000px;border:1px solid red">
 Hello World 
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>teststetest

</div>
```

So you can get an idea from above example, any invalid HTML in those third party sites can broke your HTML structure.